# Libgdx: redirect to url through post request

Tags: java, android, libgdx, payment-gateway, skrill

I need to integrate skrill with an android and a web libgdx game. Skrill gives a url and recommend using post request to call the api.

How to do so from within the libgdx game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might need some more info, but java.net package can be used in libGDX so you could do exactly the same way as you would a normal Java application